# Missing shared library for Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

After I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 my rhythmbox wouldn't work. After many failed attempts I ended up uninstalling and removing all traces of rhythmbox I could find. Now I've reinstalled rhythmbox, and am getting the error

```
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: librhythmbox-core.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install librhythmbox*`

Only to get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'librhythmbox-core5' for regex 'librhythmbox*'
Note, selecting 'librhythmbox-core6' for regex 'librhythmbox*'
Note, selecting 'librhythmbox-core7' for regex 'librhythmbox*'
librhythmbox-core7 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Any ideas on how to get rhythmbox back to a working state?

I've now reinstalled librhythmboxcore7 using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install librhythmbox-core7` and am getting a different error much closer to my original problem when I first upgraded (though I don't think it's exactly the same). `(rhythmbox:22288): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_add_from_file: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

And now with fossfreedoms instruction, `sudo apt-get --reinstall install gir1.2-rb-3.0 librhythmbox-core7 rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins` has allowed me to begin using rhythmbox once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably that you need to trick `apt` to reinstall the library even though its already installed.  This should force the correct symlinks such as you have reported to be recreated corrected.

Take for example this:

```
dad@dad-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install librhythmbox-core7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
librhythmbox-core7 is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  cmake-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As you can see, a simple install of the package `librhythmbox-core7` will not work.

```
dad@dad-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install librhythmbox-core7
[sudo] password for dad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  cmake-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/457 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 195782 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace librhythmbox-core7 2.99.1-0ubuntu1 (using .../librhythmbox-core7_2.99.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement librhythmbox-core7 ...
Setting up librhythmbox-core7 (2.99.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
dad@dad-VirtualBox:~$
```

By using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install librhythmbox-core7`, apt will go a fetch a new copy and install the library.

---

In a similar manner you can also force a download and reinstallation of all the core rhythmbox packages:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gir1.2-rb-3.0 librhythmbox-core7 rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried your suggestion. I'm now getting an error much closer to my original problem when I first upgraded (though I don't think it's exactly the same).

`(rhythmbox:22288): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_add_from_file: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Remember this is a Q&A site - so keep on editing your question with new information.  Strictly speaking, this is a new question - however, see my update

Comment: Ahh fantastic thank you! Rhythmbox is up and running.